# Div's not appearing in parent div container

Tags: html, css

Have to use inline styling for this (I know), but for some reason I've created a table of some sorts to appear within a Div already set up. It works fine if I place outside of the parent div, but once set up within the parent div - nothing gets displayed. Code as below:

```
<div class="culture" style=" display: none;">
    <div style=" background-color: #373a36;">
         <h2 style=" color: #fff; text-align: center;">TARGETS</h2>
    </div>

    <div style=" width: 30%; background-color: #d6d2c4;">
        <h3 style=" text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">BY 31DECEMBER 2016</h3>

             <div style=" padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
             </div>
     </div>

    <div style=" width: 30%; background-color: #f3f1ed; float: left;">
       <h3 style=" text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">BY 31 DECEMBER 2017</h3>

           <div style=" padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
               <p>Content goes here</p>
           </div>
    </div>

   <div style=" width: 30%; background-color: #d6d2c4; float: left;">
        <h3 style=" text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">FROM 2018 TO 2020</h3>

            <div style=" padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Do I need to add in div clears? Could use a little help here.

Comment: What content is not displaying? Also could you tab your tags to make them more readable?

Comment: Basically all the content once clicked on the <div class="culture"> isn't showing.

Comment: Why do you use inline styles instead of putting your styles into `<style>` or calling a .css file?

Comment: Unfortunately for this particular page I don't have access to the CSS file (restrictions at work). So I have had to resort to inline for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

In the 7th line you have this `style=" display: none;"`.

This CSS makes the div and all it's children hidden.

Remove it and you'll see the rest of the content

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qqo2mxrg/)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. These "display:none" are on all of the tabs so that all the content doesn't appear on the first <li>. The others have them and are displaying content just fine. I've got a feeling it might have to do with the width or something.

Comment: Then you'll have to explain what content do you expect to see. It would be easier if you'll remove all the irrelevant code so we can focus on the problem.

Comment: Basically all the content once clicked on the <div class="culture"> isn't showing.

Comment: `display: none;` means you can't see the content, if you won't remove it, you won't be able to see this div...it's that simple. Other `div`s as you mentioned might have another class that overrides this style...